# Search and erase char array

Tags: c

I am trying to parse through an array for a char and delete everything after that. I did write the code to find the location of the char search in the array. How to delete the remaining part of the array after the identified location. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [memset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memset/):

```
memset(&arr[current_location], 0, sizeof(arr) - current_location);
```

To set all bytes in `arr` after `current_location` contain `0`

Answer (score 2):

In C the easiest way to do it is like this:

```
str[end_idx] = '\0';
```

This cuts off the string at a particular index because C strings are [null terminated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string).

Comment: I want to delete the array content and not NULL terminate it.

Comment: Aha, well... ambiguity at its finest.

Comment: Not ambiguous at all, IMO, since he spoke about a char array, and not about a string.

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis: ...which are exactly the same thing in C

Comment: Technically, they may be, but I assume you'll agree that semantically, they are not. A string is interpreted as text terminated by a zero char, an array is just a sequence of characters, and zero chars have no special meaning.